# How to write a test to handle an Axios error

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a GET Axios request in which I pass a github user and get information about him. I need to process the option when the request gives an error, which I process in catch (). How can i do this?

```js
//get user

async componentDidMount() {
  getUser(this.props.user)
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      this.setState({
        error: "request error"
      });
    });
}
```

```js
//jest

jest.mock("axios");

describe("UserList Component", () => {
  it("should return user login", async () => {
    const user = { data: "login1" };
    axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(user);
    const res = await getUser(user);
    expect(res.data).toContain("login1");
  });
  it("should return error", async () => {
   //Here I need to write a test in which I check the error so that the error text matches
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test axios both success and failure case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57835066/how-to-test-axios-both-success-and-failure-case)

Comment: It is necessary for me not in the console that deduced. Whether and checked such text in an error. I tried this code and it didn't pass my test

Comment: Are you trying to test the case where the request finishes but with a non-2xx status code, or where the request fails entirely? It's not even clear _what_ you're testing - the description says the component, but nothing's rendered in the test, you're directly calling the method. The short answer is: your test double (`axios.get`, in this case, but if you're actually testing the component maybe it should be `getUser`) needs to simulate the failure, likely by `mockRejected` instead of `mockResolved`. Have a look at https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous.

Answer (score -1):

this is the answer [testing the catch block using jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254304/testing-the-catch-block-using-jest)

```
expect(() => {
   const model = new Sample(resolvedSample)
}).toThrow(TypeError);
```